# How to open wikipedia home page with already entered a specific test in the search bar

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm opening this wikipedia page [image]

by pushing a button and i'm using this code to do it

```
let urlW = URL(string: "https://www.wikipedia.org")
    let svm = SFSafariViewController.init(url: urlW!)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svm, animated: true)
```

what i would like to know if is possibile to open the same page with already entered a specific text in the search bar, for example "colosseum" or something like that; how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer:** Use the URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search={search term}

If you goto the website and do a basic search for something you will normally end up at a URL like `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum`

If you mispell the search term and the website does not get a good match, you will get a URL like `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=coloesumn`

If I use this URL for easy searches, such as tank

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=tank`

I get redirected to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank`

So in short you should be fine to use the following URL

Use the URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search={search term}